# Overload a Block in local Module (sales_order_grid)

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, module

I am trying to overload the core/mage/adminhtml/sales/order/grid.php Block. The Problem is, the Block is already overwritten by another Module (Raveinfosys Deleteorder). 
So i have to try, to overload the grid.php of the local Module Deleteorder... but it doesnt work... :(

Thats what i try last:

etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <company_modulename>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Adminhtml />
            <Raveinfosys_Deleteorder />
        </depends>
    </company_modulename>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <deleteorder>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </deleteorder>  
    </blocks>     
</global>
```

Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
class Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

But how can i manually manage the hierarchy when i am not able to rewrite the custom module file? i need to rewrite the deleteorder class, because that on is rewriting the core file.

i want to do: myClass extends deleteorderClass, deleteorderClass extends coreClass (without changing the deleteorder module files)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually manage the hierarchy in the block php files. Class A extends B, B extends C, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite the main Mage_Adminhtml block then you can simply extends the other modules block and this should give you the desired results.

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
        <sales_order_grid>Company_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

The problem with using `<deleteorder>` and trying to rewrite that is it is never called as it rewrites the `<adminhtml>` section.

*Note: You then have to be careful when trying to get the code from the two blocks working together*